# Getting the address of a DNS server programmatically in Java

Tags: java, dns

Is it possible to programmatically get the address of the DNS server that's going to be used when I do my hostname resolution? I'd like to do this in a platform independent way in Java. I know there is some way to do it in Linux, some Windows APIs, etc., but can I get to this stuff from Java?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15239220/java-dnslookup-get-dns-attributes

Comment: No it isn't. This gets information about a nameserver once you know what it is. I want to know how to find which nameserver is going to be used.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [dnsjava](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/dnsjava/dnsjava):

```java
import org.xbill.DNS.*;

String dnsServers[] = ResolverConfig.getCurrentConfig().servers();
```

(however you can't know which of the potentially multiple servers will be used for a given lookup)

Comment: note: on my fairly standard Ubuntu 16.04 installation this gives you just `127.0.1.1` which is the local dnsmasq(?) dns cache server

Comment: Does `/etc/resolv.conf` also contain 127.0.0.1 or does `nslookup www.stackoverflow.com` also show a line `Server: 127.0.0.1` (see also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28941 ) ? If that's the case I guess it is difficult to impossible to know what the DNS server behind the caching one is without knowing how the 'behind' is setup.

Comment: `resolv.conf` contains just `nameserver 127.0.1.1` and `nslookup` as expected `Server:  127.0.1.1` - once you ask networkmanager about dns for the connection you get to see that the primary dns is a device on the local network in my case, so not that useful either but you're at least outside the pc.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what vendor VM you're using, you can do it by using either JNDI or a vendor-specific API (Sun/Oracle's in this case). Check [this post](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t63666.html) which describes both.

I'm currently looking for a way to do the same on OpenJDK and will post details if I find anything.

EDIT: Looks like those [classes](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/com/sun/jndi/dns/DnsContextFactory.html) are also available on the OpenJDK, interesting...

Answer (score 0):

JDK 8 example:

```
...
import sun.net.dns.ResolverConfiguration;
...
List nameServers = ResolverConfiguration.open().nameservers();
nameServers.forEach((dns)->System.out.println(dns));
...
```